# QT keyPressedEvent too slow?

Tags: c++, performance, qt, qgraphicsscene

I'm developing a shoot'em up with qt creator and my problem is the link with the `keyPressEvent` function of my scene:

```
void Scene::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event){
    liste_event << event->key();

    if (liste_event.contains(Qt::Key_Left)) {
        vaisseau->MoveX(-1);
    }

    if (liste_event.contains(Qt::Key_Right)) {
        vaisseau->MoveX(1);
    }
}
```

It compiles, but my sprite (vasisseau) moves very slowly. How can I improve the code so it moves faster?

Comment: It looks like what you probably want is to keep moving the sprite while the key is pressed.  I would suggest starting a QTimer which moves the sprite when it fires.

Comment: Do you mean the keypressevent function have to call a QTimer ?

Comment: Yes, if you want the sprite to keep moving until the key is released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, **the problem is that you are leaving the animation of the game to the `keyPressEvent`**, which is not triggered as often as you would like.

To solve this problem I suggest you use the traditional approach, which involves having an function to `draw()` the scene (and it's objects). The idea is that this function is called every X miliseconds, and the drawing will work independently of a key being pressed or not.

So in this case, inside `keyPressEvent` you would just store the key that was pressed, and in `Scene::draw()` you will implement the logic that will call `MoveX()` with the appropriate parameter, based on the stored key.